# When is it better to fry with oil and when is it better to fry with butter?

Tags: frying

I usually see people frying eggs with butter and sometimes with soy oil - for example. But there are a lot of other ocasions in which these two options appear. My guess is that there are kinds of frying, for example: When you want to fry eggs, it's better to do it with butter, this is a kind of lighter frying. But when you are frying chips, it's better to do it with oil, this is a kind of heavy frying in which the food much receive more heat for a long time (I guess that oil can reach temperatures higher than butter).

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25469/why-does-my-olive-oil-smoke-burn-when-i-fry-with-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it all depends on temperature:

Every fat or oil has a specific smoke point ([see here for a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_point)), at which temperature it starts to degrade. That means, not all oils are suitable for every heat, or all types of frying. Some types of oil should remain "cold", like extra-virgin olive oil.

Butter  has a rather low smoke point (325-375 °F or 163-190 °C) due to milk solids. So, frying with butter is a bit tricky temperature-wise, but often butter is choosen for taste. (Clarified butter, on the other hand, has a smoke point of ca. 485 °F or 252 °C, which makes it usable for pan- or deep-frying. The taste is somewhat similar to butter, but not equal.)

As eggs are typically fried at a "low" temperature, using butter is fine. An example from the opposite end of the heat range would be asian cuisine, where food is prepared in a wok at very high heat. (I won't give recommendations what to use & when, as there are subtle differences, even between brands. If in doubt, read the label.)

So, to cut a long story short: 
Decide what you want to do, how hot your pan is going to be and pick the matching oil.