# Frying olive oil is bad for your health, but cooking with it in an oven?

Tags: baking, olive-oil

Always heard that olive oil is bad for frying food (mostly for health reason), so it's better to use other type of oil to cook, but what about of using olive oil to cook in an oven? it would be the same as frying?

Comment: Hey, Progs!  Per our Help center, we don't answer questions about the health value of foods on SA.  Sorry.

Comment: The root cause for the question is thermal degradation and unwanted compounds due to olive oil having a low smoke point, which has also been answered here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/25469/why-does-my-olive-oil-smoke-burn-when-i-fry-with-it?rq=1 and here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6148/is-cooking-with-olive-oil-bad-or-toxic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is cooking with olive oil bad or toxic?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6148/is-cooking-with-olive-oil-bad-or-toxic)

Comment: @FuzzyChef this question was incorrectly flagged as off-topic. The author cited health concerns as context for the question, but specifically asked a technical question to prevent that context scenario; the answer to which has been provided in multiple historical questions. This was better flagged as duplicate.

Comment: No, it's really not.  The core of the question is "if olive oil is unhealthy for frying, is it unhealthy to use it in the oven".  And that's not a question we can answer, because we can't answer questions about olive oil being "unhealthy".  Thanks for flagging those old questions, though, I'll flag them for closure as well.

Comment: Particularly, we cannot answer it because we cannot determine why the OP thinks olive oil is "unhealthy".

Answer (score 2):

The concern for frying with olive oil is heating it past its smoke point, causing it to break down. Olive oil in the oven does not have the same issue if it is heated below the smoke point - like with olive oil cake recipes.